# Scala package object does not bring companion object into scope?

Tags: scala

Developed a small package object that looks like this:

```
package object logic {

  type Chat = engine.logic.chat.Chat
  type History = engine.logic.history.History
  type Meta = engine.logic.meta.Meta
  type Notification = engine.logic.notification.Notification
  type Service = engine.logic.service.Service
  type State = engine.logic.state.State
  type Sync = engine.logic.sync.Sync

}
```

Looks like I am misunderstanding the point of the package object since I was under the belief that the preceding would bring the companion object `Sync` into scope.

`Sync` is a top-level object under `package engine.logic.sync`.

Here is how I am accessing it:

`engine.logic.Sync.aMemberDef(var: String)`

However the compiler throws an error `object Sync is not a member of package engine.logic`. So what's the workaround and how did I mess up my packaging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create instance alias, just use val:

```
val Sync = engine.logic.sync.Sync
```